# Spring Boot JPA MySQL : Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating an application using Spring Boot JPA, I am using MySQL as a database.

Following is my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I have added following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

When I checked in debug logs I can see mysql java connector in my classpath but still I am getting following errors

> 2019-07-29 10:03:00.742  INFO 10356 --- [           main]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
>   embedded WebApplicationContext 2019-07-29 10:03:00.742  INFO 10356 ---
>   [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1534 ms 2019-07-29
>   10:03:00.789  WARN 10356 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method
>   'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Failed to determine a suitable driver class 2019-07-29 10:03:00.789 
>   INFO 10356 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2019-07-29 10:03:00.805  INFO 10356 --- [           main]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-07-29 10:03:00.805
>   ERROR 10356 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).

Answer (score -11, accepted):

It was some mistake in my configuration which I couldn't detect, I re-created same project and things started working

Comment: Is this kind of answer supposed to be accepted?

Comment: You should point out the issue that blocked you.

Answer (score 14):

Spring Boot auto-configuration tries to configure the beans automatically based on the dependencies added to the classpath. Since you have the JPA dependency on your classpath, Spring Boot tries to automatically configure a JPA DataSource. The problem is, you haven’t given Spring the complete information it needs to perform the auto-configuration.

Add this missing property to your `application.properties` file, so that spring can autoconfigure

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Another way you can define your data source programmatically, by using the utility builder class DataSourceBuilder. For that you need to provide the database URL, username, password, and the SQL driver information to create your data source:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb")
                .username("root")
                .password("pass")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also but still continue to get same error. Am I missing something else?

Comment: try this `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. And let me know.

Comment: try changing it to "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" for my-sql connector version 8.0 and above.

Comment: @kashishverma  I tried your suggestions but unfortunately things don't seem to work. Thanks for your help. Let me just delete the project and create a new one

Comment: Please, indicate packages... It's a pain in the ass to find which one should be used... (what package is DataSource from ?)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by doing right click on the project, maven/update project, then you should select your project and accept.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. My solution is : open module settings,and select resources,and right click it ,and select "Test Resources". Then it's solved.

[image: setting page]

Answer (score 1):

Spring Autoconfigure looks for 2 properties to load the appropriate driver,

1. spring.datasource.driverClassName (in this case the value would be 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' from MySQL connector 4.4.1.3 onwards)
2. spring.datasource.url (in this case it is jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb)

Actually Spring Autoconfigure just need spring.datasource.url and it can derive the driver class name from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your application organization looked like :

**Commons**
->
**Module1**

**Commons** was a parent to **Module1**.

I had created a **BaseEntity** having JPA annotations in my commons module. The commons dependency was specified as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Once I added the provided

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The issue got resolved for me. Unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error whenever I created the Spring Data JPA project. In my .classpath file of project I saw that the resources folder was excluded so I removed that and got the error resolved.

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/mydb
```